# Save increment in C

Tags: c, store

I need a little help with something I'm writing C.

So I have this:

```
int a;
int one = 4;
int two = 3;
printf("If you have done this then write '1', if you have done that write '2' ");
scanf("%d" ,&a);
if (a=1)
   {
     one = one+1;
    }
else if (a=2)
   {
    two = two+1
   }
```

So the thing I want to do is to save that increment so the next time I open the program, the values of int one and two will change based on the last usage of the program.
How do I do this ?

Comment: `int one = 4`? That's just... wrong. next up: `#define TRUE 0`

Comment: One `=` is assignment. Two `==` is comparison. Your compiler should be warning you about this. If not, use `-Wall`.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but `if (a=1)` is always true, because you have used the assignment operator (single `=`) instead of the comparison operator (`==`).

Comment: You will need to save this information to a file.

Comment: Answers below recommend you FILE I/O and they are correct but I think you should rather get comfortable writing simple C programmes then later return to this problem. Find a tutorial page that teaches C and suits you and as you learn find some simple exercises to complete. Exercises like these http://www.cprogramming.com/challenge.html

Answer (score 2):

Use fopen/fread/fclose when you start the application (before write checks if the FILE handle is correctly created)

Use fopen/fwrite/fclose when you exit from the application.

How to access file? very basic functionalities, read this:
http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/07/c-file-handling/

Answer (score 0):

Read both variables from file and write it to the file before closing the program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a;
    FILE *fp = fopen("save.txt", "r+"); // File contains two integers 4 3
    int one;
    int two;
    fscanf(fp, "%d %d", &one, &two);
    printf("%d %d\n", one, two);
    printf("If you have done this then write '1', if you have done that write '2' ");
    scanf("%d" ,&a);
    if (a==1)
    {
        one = one+1;
    }
    else if (a==2)
    {
        two = two+1;
    }
    rewind(fp);
    fprintf(fp,"%d %d\n", one, two);
}
```

Comment: Although one/two only grow, both in numeric and string representations, it is still unsafe in development and support perspective to just rewind file without truncating. Should put '\n' in fprintf at least?

Answer (score 0):

When the program finishes processing it is removed from the memory along with it's variables. What you what to achieve requires file handling. See this tutorial - http://www.w3schools.in/c/file-handling/

A couple of suggestions:

1 - It's supposed to be `if (a==1)`

2 - It's always recommended to add the `else` block for a `if..else if` control block to handle any unexpected input